# How can I both get raw post data and use Apache2::Request to access parameters?

Tags: perl, mod-perl2

Apache2::Request doesn't seem to provide a way to get the raw post data; is there one that I am missing?

Alternatively, is there a way to read the post data separately (in a content handler - nothing should have messed with the post data before then) and initialize Apache2::Request with it?

Comment: `$r->read($postdata, $r->headers_in('content_length')); $r->args($postdata);`?

Answer (score 0):

from mod_perl cookbook:

```
my $r = shift;

my $content;
$r->read($content,$r->header_in('Content-length'));

my @pairs = split(/[&;]/,$content);

foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
    my ($parameter,$value) = split('=',$pair,2);
}
```

Comment: that doesn't allow using Apache2::Request to look at the parameters too.